# Be vs being in "Being in a great team" when answering "the best things in our company".

Tags: grammar

I am asked to list "the best things in our company". I want to say that the team I am in is great. But I think it should be a noun to be filled in the blank to answer the question. So I think "being in a great team" should be filled in, am I correct?

Comment: General reference: [Gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Examples_of_use) Is a noun or behaves in specific cases like a noun. A paint*ing*, a human be*ing* are nouns, but *I like `being` a painter* or *I like `painting` humans*

Answer (score 1):

Yes 'being' is a gerund and hence a noun.  I suppose you could also use the infinitive 'To be in a good team'. But 'be' on its own does not, it seems to me, grammatically answer the question.

However I'm not clear that it answers a question about "the best things in our company". It seems like an answer to "Why do you like working in our company?".